# Software that plays .m3u8 stream file over VPN on ASP.NET web page

Tags: video, web-browser, gopro

I have a GoPro Hero 3+.  After some hacking, I can do a live view stream via VLC Player (after setting it on loop).  However, I want to add a live stream to my ASP.NET web page (C#).  I've tried a few things.

**HTML5:**

```
<video src="http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8"
        autoplay="true"
        controls="false">
 </video>
```

**JW Player:**

```
<div id='goproherolive'></div>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/9Xd9rv1IEeKDbSIACusDuQ.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('goproherolive').setup({
        file: 'http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8',
        //file: 'http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba_hls-1.ts',
        //file: 'C:\Users\msalim\Videos\GOPR0652.MP4',
        title: 'GoPro HERO Live Stream',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        fallback: 'false',
        autostart: 'true',
        repeat: 'true'
    });
</script>
```

**VLC.DotNet:**

```
<Wpf:VlcControl x:Name="myVlcControl" />

<Grid Grid.Row="0">
     <Grid.Background>
         <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
             <VisualBrush.Visual>
                 <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=myVlcControl, Path=http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8}" />
             </VisualBrush.Visual>
         </VisualBrush >
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Found [here](https://github.com/RexGrammer/Vlc.DotNet).  I don't know why but this just doesn't bring up anything on my webpage.  The others at least give me a video screen with an error.

None of these work. I'd prefer anything free and that is compatible with ASP.NET 4.5.  It could be HTML, JavaScript, C#, or anything else that runs smoothly with ASP.NET.  I just want to be able to stream it via a web page on all common browsers (Internet Explore, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari).

Please note that the path/source of the video is over VPN: `http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8`

The GoPro also produces .ts files.  If there is a way to put those together and play those, then that's acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just jumped the gun on this one, but I found a working solution with some browsers using VLC Web Plugin:

```
<!-- VLC Web Plugin in works! (for some browsers...) -->
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="video1" autoplay="no" loop="yes" width="400" height="300" target="http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8" /> 
<br /> 
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.play()'>Play video1</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.pause()'>Pause video1</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.stop()'>Stop video1</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='document.video1.fullscreen()'>Fullscreen</a>
```

NOTE:  It plays standard ratio (not HD).  It's also a bit laggy.